# How to save user input drawing over image to photo gallery

Tags: swift, image, calayer, uibezierpath, photo-gallery

My code successful saves a image to the photo gallery however what I drew over that image is not being saved on top of it. So my code needs to save the image and the user input drawing. Right now it just saves the image.

```
 var nextPage = UIButton()
    var clear = UIButton()
    var submitToDB = UIButton()





    var myLayer = CALayer()
    var path = UIBezierPath()
    var startPoint = CGPoint()
    var touchPoint = CGPoint()



    var playName = UITextField()





    var drawPlace = UIImageView()//The imageview






    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let point = touch?.location(in: drawPlace){
            startPoint = point

        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let point = touch?.location(in: drawPlace){
            touchPoint = point
        }

        path.move(to: startPoint)
        path.addLine(to: touchPoint)
        startPoint = touchPoint
        draw()
    }
    func draw() {
        submitToDB.layer.cornerRadius = 0
        drawPlace.clipsToBounds = true
        drawPlace.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
        let strokeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        strokeLayer.fillColor = nil
        strokeLayer.lineWidth = 5
        strokeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        strokeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        drawPlace.layer.insertSublayer(strokeLayer, below: myLayer)
        drawPlace.setNeedsDisplay()


        let star:UIImage = UIImage(named: "bb.png")!
        let newSize = CGSize(width: star.size.width, height: star.size.height  )

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, star.scale)



        star.draw(in: CGRect(x: newSize.width/10.6,
                             y: newSize.height/8,
                             width: newSize.width/1.2,
                             height: newSize.height/1.2),
                  blendMode:CGBlendMode.normal, alpha:1)



        let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


        drawPlace.image = newImage





    }
    func save() {




        guard let selectedImage = drawPlace.image else {
            print("Image not found!")
            return
        }
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(selectedImage, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }
```

I guess I need to somehow save the layer over the image being saved I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make capture from the `UIImageView`, so try this:

Add extension to `UIView` to make a capture:

```
extension UIView {
    func screenshot() -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size).image { _ in
            drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bounds.size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

After that, change your `save()` to this:

```
func save() {
    let image = drawPlace.screenshot()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,  #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}
```